# Are there any studies on whether code-switching happens more amongst more closely related languages?

Tags: code-switching

I've been looking pretty diligently to try to find any studies that may point to any information regarding code-switching and its frequency among different types of languages, but am not having a lot of luck so far.

I would be curious to know, for instance, if code-switching tends to happen amongst bilingual groups when the languages are more closely related. In my personal experience, I've heard bilingual English-German speakers code-switch much more often than bilingual English-Korean speakers, and while it could be just my own experience, it could be a real phenomenon either due to social circumstances or linguistic circumstances.

Does anyone know of a study on this subject (even if it's something that might just help as a stepping stone to finding further studies)?

Comment: I don't know any studies, but I doubt this would be the case. Code switching happens when one speech community frequently uses multiple languages. An example would be in Singapore, where code switching between English, Malay, and Chinese (Hokkien/Mandarin?) happens frequently, even though those three languages aren't related.

Comment: I don’t know of any studies either, but my own personal experience also doesn’t support this being the case. Living in Copenhagen, I come across a lot of Swedes and Norwegians who might code-switch between Danish and their native (more or less mutually intelligible) native languages – but code-switching doesn’t seem very common among them to me. Admixture is more common. Conversely, there are a lot of people around where I live who code-switch constantly between Danish and unrelated languages, the most common ones being Arabic, Somalian and Turkish.